# what is the difference between 4 padding for all directions and just 1 padding?

Tags: android, xml, padding

[Just using one padding but the result is not what I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7oKe.png)

> android:padding="16dp"

[So I change to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi4Gj.png)

```
android:paddingEnd="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingStart="16dp"
```

but I don't know the difference

Comment: The first one will give padding on 4 sides : 
Top
Bottom
Left
Right

The 2nd one will give padding on just Left and Right.

Answer (score 0):

paddingEnd and paddingStart are not the same as paddingTop and paddingBottom. I think that's the little catch here.

The first essentially give padding on top, bottom, left , right. "start" and "end" have a different meaning

Answer (score 0):

`android:padding="16dp"` equals to

```
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:padding="16dp"` makes paddings in all 4 directions, so when you used this it added padding from `Top` and `Bottom` and caused your view to be cropped from top and bottom.

```
android:paddingEnd="16dp"
android:paddingStart="16dp"
```

are adding padding just to left and right and not top or bottom. that the reason it will look ok when you are adding these. btw when you are using `End` - `Start` you dont need to use `right` `left` anymore